# Safari on OSX closes all tabs (crash?) after playing a YouTube video

Tags: macos, safari, video, youtube, tabs

MacOS Catalina 10.15.7

Sometimes Safari (14.0.1) closes all open tabs after playing a YouTube video (most often in full-screen mode).

My typical scenario:

1. I have several opened tabs
2. I watch a youtube video in fullscreen mode in a tab
3. I close the tab using <kbd>Cmd-W</kbd>
4. I find Safari in the dock without any opened tabs

Is it a well-known bug or my local issue? Any ideas on how to fix/workaround it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I follow to advice from [the link](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4439369?answerId=20042152022#20042152022) and determine that Grammarly addon crash my Safri.